# how to remove special characters (ex:MontrÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©al-Rive-Sud) from mysql databse

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, feed, htmlspecialchars

how to remove special characters

```
MontrÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©al-Rive-Sud
```

the above one is city name this i'm getting from xml feeds. It is directly inserting into my mysql database. now i want to remove this kind of special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `mysql_real_escape_string()`

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I've tried it its not working.. "select * from cities where city =".mysql_real_escape_string('MontrÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©al-Rive-Sud').""

Comment: He means you have to use it BEFORE adding data to your table. The bad looking string is the result of unescaped data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got an encoding problem there, that string appears to be encoded in UTF-8 and interpreted as ASCII four times:

`MontrÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â©al-Rive-Sud`
`MontrÃƒÂ©al-Rive-Sud`
`MontrÃ©al-Rive-Sud`
`Montréal-Rive-Sud`

Reminds me of:

[image: Ode to a shipping label]